# Tkinter white window

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, python-3.5

I made a multithread program in Python 3.5 using Tkinter.

When I start the program it doesn't give any error, but it makes a completely white window.
I also try to stop the GUI thread, but the program doesn't quit...

Thanks for any answer.

```
import datetime
import imaplib
import os
import queue
import requests
import smtplib
import sqlite3
import threading
import time

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from tkinter import *

class StartGUI(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        self.GUI = GUI(None)
        self.GUI.title('Eve 3.0')
        self.GUI.mainloop()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

class GUI(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.outTxt = Text(self, height=5)
        self.outTxt.grid(column=0, columnspan=3)

        self.eraseButton = Button(
            self, bg='#424242', fg='white', text='Erase', command=self.eraseInput)
        self.inTxt = Entry(self, bg='#424242', fg='white')  # , height=2)
        self.submitButton = Button(
            self, bg='#424242', fg='white', text='Submit', command=self.submitInput)

        self.eraseButton.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='EW')
        self.inTxt.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='EW')
        self.submitButton.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='EW')

    def eraseInput(self):
        self.inTxt.delete(0, END)

    def submitInput(self):
        input = self.inTxt.get()
        self.inTxt.delete(0, END)
        print(input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUIThread = StartGUI()
    GUIThread.start()
    GUIThread.stop()
    stopped = GUIThread.stopped()
```

Edit:
The window is completely white, eve the overlay that is specific of the operative system doesn't render...

Comment: In your `GUI` class, specifically in its `initialize`   method, you're calling at the very beginning `self.grid()`, why? From what I know, tkinter runs on its own thread of execution, and I don't understand why you're trying to create another thread. Any specific reason for doing that?

Comment: I am doing that to separate the "core" (with lots of if/elif statements) and an update function (with a while loop that runs every second) of the application for the GUI, I already did that, but I saw that when I run the application (core and update in a separate thread, and GUI in main thread) whenever I parse the input from the GUI to the core or the update runs, the GUI freeze... That's why I was trying to run the GUI on a different thread.

Comment: I've used threads once to create a simple "console" or "terminal" using tkinter. Check out this repository: https://github.com/dossan/tkinter/blob/master/personal/widgets/Console.py, hoping that it helps...